# I thought views/layouts/application.html.erb was meant to apply to all layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I am trying to design my ruby on rails app at the moment. I created views/layouts/posts.html.erb which styled my `PostsController`'s views.

I want to add a main bar that is always at the top of the page no matter what view the user is looking at. I thought this was what the `views/layouts/application.html.erb` was for.

This seems to agree with me:
http://jacqueschirag.wordpress.com/2007/08/02/rails-layout-and-nested-layout-basics/

> - The entire Rails application (all views of all controllers) will
>     use this layout:
>
>   `views/layouts/application.rhtml`
> - All views within a single controller will use this layout. For
>     example, the layout for
>     weclome_controller.rb will use this
>     layout. Notice, the ‘_controller’ is
>     left off for the layout:
>
>   `views/layouts/welcome.rhtml`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have in the body of my `application.html.erb`

```
  <div id="top-bar">
      <div id="user_nav">
        <% if current_user %>
          <%= link_to "My Profile", current_user %>
          <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
          <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your layouts, `application.html.erb` and `posts.html.erb` should render the main bar as a partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/main_bar' %>
```

All layouts contain the `<html>` element that wraps your page; you don't have one layout wrapping around the other.

Comment: Thanks but with that code I am getting: "Missing partial layouts/main_bar"

Comment: Err.. I forgot to put in the underscore in the filename. Thanks for you help. I'll mark this answer as the correct one since you showed how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well the information is correct - 'views/layouts/application.html.erb' should be working just fine.
Have you included the "main bar" content using `<%= ..... %>` (i.e. are you missing the `=` sign in your layout file?)
And, have you included the `<%= yield %>` statement somewhere in the layout file?

Also, what version of Rails are you using?

You should find this [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) very helpful in getting to the basics of rails views and layouts

Comment: I have added the body of my application.html.erb file to the main question. I am using Rails 3. I have just realised that I have all the <html><head></head><body></body></html> in my post.html.erb layout. Am I supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused… do you still have views/layouts/posts.html.erb ? If that's the case all views rendered from PostsController will use this layout and not views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: This "answer" should have been a comment